# How to detect availability of a parameter of given type in variadic funtion arguments list and act after all parameters have been processed

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, fold-expression

I have the following `operator<<()` overload for my class with C++17 folds:

```
template <typename... Args>
ostream& operator <<(Args&&... args)
{
    //Currently:
    return (m_osCout << ... << args);

    //What I need:
    IF ANY OF THE parameters in args "was" of type, say TSeek,  
    which can be a manipulator function etc,  then AFTER finishing 
    with the parameter pack, I would like to do some further operation
    , for instance, restore the state of m_osCount
 }
```

Is it possible what I need as described above? Any partial responses to set some directions would be appreciated...

Despite I coined the question as if I was asking for an automated stream flag restorer, please note that I am after the general solution, not particularly restoring `std::cout` or o/istream object restoration.
In practice my class is a kind of mathematical object that accepts custom-types as operator arguments, some of which requires ostream's manipulators-like functions but it is generally very very inconvenient to require user to supply some finalizing operands before starting a next such usage.

One idea that came to me was to return a different kind of temporary object of a new smart type whenever `TSeek` was provided in `args...` list, so that after the last argument is forwarded to it, it will be destructed automatically and this really is the time that I want to do my finalizing task!

Should I proceed like this or...?

Comment: For starters, an `<<` overload will always have exactly one parameter. What you need to do is even simpler than you think. You will always have exactly one parameter. A parameter pack, here, accomplishes absolutely nothing useful, whatsoever.

Comment: That's right!
I should have used a member function instead of operator<<()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... as far I know, a stream `operator<<()` must receive *exactly* two arguments.

So you can't define a variadic `operator<<()`.

If you accept a generic template variadic function, `foo()` by example, if you can use C++17 isn't really difficult.

To check the presence of a type `TSeek` in `Args...` pack, you can write something as

```
constexpr bool withTSeek { (std::is_same<Args, TSeek>{} || ...) };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct TSeek
 { };

std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & o, TSeek const &)
 { return o << " [TSeek!] "; }

template <typename ... Args>
std::ostream & foo (std::ostream & o, Args && ... args)
 {
   constexpr bool withTSeek { (std::is_same<Args, TSeek>{} || ...) };

   (o << ... << args);

   if ( withTSeek )
      o << " --- TSeek detected" << std::endl;
   else 
      o << " --- TSeek NOT detected" << std::endl;

   return o;
 }

int main ()
 {
   foo(std::cout, 1, 2, TSeek{}, 5, 7);
   foo(std::cout, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23);
 }
```

Comment: How simple it was! Many thanks! Exact solution for my specific problem even if i might have implied something different in my question body...
Despite ostream was just for problem-statement purposes only, then can't we use this approach to restore ostream flag states only by extending your solution to detect manipulator functions? Idea is that if if withTSeek_Manipulator is true, first save the flags, do streaming and check flag again to restore it...

Comment: @mami: This is doable, but it will require a type-trait to detect whether it's a stream manipulator. This should be similar to the way the `withTSeek` is written -- except for your case you should be able to base it on whether the argument is invocable with an `ostream`. You might be able to use something like `(std::is_invocable<Args, std::ostream&>{} || ...)` to detect this. Then in C++17 you can use `static if` to create compile-time scopes that only expand if the expression resolves `true` -- which gives you your two cases: with and without manipulators.